# Passing an unknown type Object to a function

Tags: c#, winforms

So this is my code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Light" && Form.ActiveForm.Name != "Light")
        {
            Light o = new Light();
            o.Show();
            o.listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            NeedsToClose = false;
            this.Close();
        }
        else if(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Acceleration"&& Form.ActiveForm.Name !="Acceleration")
        {
            Acceleration o = new Acceleration();
            o.Show();
            o.listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            NeedsToClose = false;
            this.Close();
        }

    }
```

It works, but as you can see I have this part of code in both cases:

```
o.Show();
o.listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
NeedsToClose = false;
this.Close();
```

I would like to make it function(void) instead, pass an object to it, and get a result. Any ideas how this can be done?

Both Forms derive from form called Template,which derives from class Form.

Comment: Assuming `Acceleration` and `Light` derive from a common class which derives from `Form`?

Comment: From another parent form Called Template

Comment: What would the return value be?  A boolean?

Comment: I thought about void function

Comment: Can you update your question to include more information (like the fact that they derive from Template, and what that class derives from)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of making this to work - statically typed and a dynamically typed.

In a statically typed way you would make an interface that covers the commonalities between `Light` and `Acceleration` forms - specifically, the fact that they both have `listBox1`. This would let C# check the presence of said commonalities at compile time. Assuming that the base class form `Template` has `listBox1`, you can do it like this:

```
Template nextForm;
if (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Light" && Form.ActiveForm.Name != "Light") {
    nextForm = new Light();
} else if(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Acceleration"&& Form.ActiveForm.Name !="Acceleration") {
    nextForm = new Acceleration();
}
nextForm.Show();
nextForm.listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
NeedsToClose = false;
this.Close();
```

In a dynamically typed solution you let C# skip the checks, with the understanding that the program would fail at runtime if the common parts are not there. The solution is identical to the above, except you use keyword `dynamic` in place of the name of the common type:

```
dynamic nextForm;
... // the rest is the same
```

Comment: +1, a more OOP approach would be to suggest him create an interface maybe "ISpeed" and then let objects "light", "speed" implement it, then on interface he can create object dynamically.. maybe you can add it to your answer :)

Comment: @ДмитрийКовалёв It depends on your personal preferences. `dynamic` is definitely more lightweight on coding, but using it comes at the price of fewer compiler checks. For example, if you or someone who modifies your code decides to give `listBox1` a better sounding name in one of the forms, your `dynamic` code will continue to compile, but it would break as soon as it tries to set `listBox1` that has been renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Few bits I wanted to improve @dasblinkenlight answer,

```
{
    Template nextForm = GetForm();
    if(nextForm == null)
       return; // throw exception otherwise

    ShowNextForm(nextForm);
    NeedsToClose = false;
    this.Close();
}

private Template GetForm()
{
    string selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string activeFormName = Form.ActiveForm.Name;
    Template nextForm;
    if (selectedItem =="Light" && activeFormName != "Light") {
        nextForm = new Light();
    } else if(selectedItem == "Acceleration"&& activeFormName !="Acceleration") {
        nextForm = new Acceleration();
    }
    return nextForm;
}

private Template ShowNextForm(Template nextForm)
{
    nextForm.Show();
    nextForm.listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```